# Primefaces Dynamic Mega Menu - Cannot remove the same component twice

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I changed my static menu file (header.xhtml) with a mega menu with a model.
Like this:

```
          <p:megaMenu model="#{menuController.megaModel}" autoDisplay="false" styleClass="menu-bar"  >

          </p:megaMenu>
```

So far so good, its working great and building just like I expected.
The problem is, on my form pages, when validation fails for the secound time...
I get this error:

```
 javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot remove the same component twice: j_idt15:j_id2     com.sun.faces.context.StateContext$AddRemoveListener.handleAddRemoveWithAutoPrune(StateContext.java:493)
        com.sun.faces.context.StateContext$AddRemoveListener.handleRemove(StateContext.java:372)
```

Looking at the generated HTML I cant find this String "j_idt15:j_id2", but I can find:

```
   <div id="j_idt14:j_idt15" class="ui-menu ui-menubar ui-megamenu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix menu-bar" role="menubar">
```

and this:

So... I really don´t understand. My MenuController is a sessionBean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MenuController implements Serializable {

@PostConstruct
   public void init(){
   todosModulos = moduloService.findAll();
   modulosAcesso = extrairModulos();
   createMegaMenu();
}
```

...So.. some notes:

I figured out that this error occurs on versions of Mojarra above 2.1.9.
(I am using 2.1.10). So one possible solution is changing the JSF imp to My Faces.
I Tried that, but it buged my structure (my composite components stoped working and dynaForm also).

I tried some workarounds but no sucess. This is what I tried:
[Overriding AbstractMenu](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23669) and [Marlon Patrick's solution (PT-BR)](http://marlonpatrick.info/blog/2013/01/24/primefaces-menu-dinamico-e-a-inofensiva-mensagem-unable-to-find-component-dot-dot-dot/).

Simply doesn´t work =[

**EDIT** -> Creating the MenuItem

```
 MenuItem anItem = new MenuItem();
 anItem.setOutcome(item.getOutcome());
 anItem.setValue(item.getRotulo());
 anItem.setIcon(item.getIcone());
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to call `anItem.setTransient(true)`? This worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I saw you already tried my two workarounds: overwrite AbstractMenu and put PhaseListener.

Well, what I realize is that the component that was the problem I had MenuBar and what you are trying to use is the MegaMenu, perhaps the solutions that I do not work for MegaMenu, although I believe that should work yes.

What I would say to you is to check the following:

1 - When you override the class AbstractMenu you are sure the PrimeFaces started to use it? To make sure it puts a break point there and if he sees to the execution flow. If you do not stop, because PrimeFaces is still using its own class.

2 - When attempting to use the solution with PhaseListener, which I prefer and use today, you noted that you need to replace a piece of code with your own code? Basically you'll have to remove only the actions of menu items that are links, because they are causing this problem. The menu items are actions that should remain. In my case, I knew what actions were or links by ID, then you will have to differentiate somehow believe that by also id. Also, put a break point to make sure that your PhaseListener was duly registered and that is intercepting the flow of execution.

Comment: Ok, lets focus on the PhaseListener solution ok? I didn´t notice. The problem is that all of my MenuItems use the setOutcome method. I´´ll edit the post to show you the piece a code

Comment: This is a very well-stated answer.  Please mark it as thus if it satisfies your ask.

Comment: Well, in my case I use setUrl (link) setActionExpression and as you can see below:
1 - menuItemLink.setUrl ("/changePassword.xhtml");
2 - menuItemAction.setActionExpression(logoutMethodExpression);

As I said, the only PhaseListener must remove the links, thus removing the actions they will not work after rendering the page.

In your case, I'm not sure what behavior with setOutcome, but is giving error as I imagine it works the same way as the setUrl and therefore can remove all menu items with setOutcome. What should permancer are only those who use setActionExpression.